# Adding custom level to bunyan instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, logging, error-logging, bunyan

I have created a logger instance of bunyan

```
export const createLogger = (
  appname: string,
) =>
  bunyan.createLogger({
    name: appname,
    streams: [
      {
        level: 'error',
        stream: process.stdout
      },
    ],
  })
```

After creating the instance of this createLogger, I am adding a stream to the createLogger instance, like this -

```
export const logs = createLogger(
  appname,
);

logs.addStream({
  name: 'logRequest',
  stream: process.stdout,
  level: 'debug',
});
```

I just want to be able to use `log.logRequest()` as a function wherever I require logging. But I keep getting this error that -

> Property 'logRequest' does not exist on type 'Logger'

Please suggest an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the name of the stream for logging, you use the log level. For instance, use

```
logs.debug('something went wrong')
logs.fatal('something REALLY went wrong')
```

Also, if you create the logger at a log level of error, you won't see debug messages, because those are lower in priority. Only log events of a higher priority will be emitted.